# Creating a responsive website header?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and I building my first website. I want to create a header that has an image in the center and the nav menu surrounding it.

Here is the code I'm working with:

HTML:

```
</head>
    <body>
    <div id ="header">    

        <div id="nav">
            <ul>

                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Philanthropy</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cosDXx1.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Why Join?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</body
```

>

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#header{
    width:100%;
    height:110px;
    background-color:black;
}

#nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family:"Slabo 13px",serif;
    float:center;
}

#nav ul li{
    padding:10px;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:60px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#006600;

}

#nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#CC0000;
}
```

JSfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/5g6sm01q/

On my screen it is in a line but when I shrink it (and in the jsfiddle example) it is not. Please any tips or help with this problem would appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Convert all the pixel values into % or atleast the padding and the left and right margins, and see the change..I've just edited your fiddle a little bit..

see this http://jsfiddle.net/5g6sm01q/2/

Chnge the css like this

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#header{
    width:100%;
    height:110px;
    background-color:black;
}

#nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family:"Slabo 13px",serif;
    float:center;
}

#nav ul li{
    padding:0.5%;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#006600;

}

#nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#CC0000;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As @Krodmannix mentioned in his comment,there is a way in CSS to dictate how to format the page based on different screen sizes using **media queries**.It makes it very easy to adapt your site to mobile screens without any page redirection

Comment: This is definitely the right way to think about it. In addition to this, look at media queries, which is a way in CSS to dictate how to format the page based on different screen sizes. It makes it very easy to adapt your site to mobile screens without any page redirection.

Comment: Yes..Thanks @Krodmannix ..very usefull suggestion...i'll mention that too in my comments... :)

Comment: Awesome. I'll definitely look into media queries. I took your suggestion and changed the margins to % but not it is very spaced out. How do I narrow the spacing between the list items?